# SQL Query including pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have done a query which include the left outer join and the pivot.
However I keep getting a bugs saying incorrect column.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(select Max(datetimestamp)as datetimestamp, currentSet, tGroup_id from tPhos_Line_Operator 
group by currentSet, tGroup_id)T
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT PO.tGroup_id AS G_ID, PO.CurrentSet AS cr,gP.tTest_id AS Header,convert(float,Po.Results) as Results from tPhos_Line_Operator PO
inner join tPhos_Line_Parameter pp
on PO.tPhos_Line_Parameter_id = PP.id
INNER JOIN tGroup_Parameter GP
on pp.tGroup_Parameter_id = gp.id
where PP.tPhosline_id=134)P
on T.tGroup_id = P.G_ID
AND T.CurrentSet = p.cr
PIVOT ( MAX(p.Results) For Header IN ([4],[23],[24])) AS pvt
```

Anyone know how to get the DateTimeStamp and the pivot record?
Which mean i will only have 4 columns in this case.

Currently i need to select * from.
I'm sorry still a junior in query.
Thanks in advance.

---

sample data could go here:

sample of expected result:

```
dateTime               | currentset | tGroup_id | G_ID | cr | 4    | 23 | 24 | 
2015-03-11 07:00:24.313      1           69      69      1   8.36    10  14.4 
2015-03-12 00:31:58.257      2           69      69      2   9.12     8  14.4
```

Comment: Spreading columns are determined by elimination. You shoul use pivot and cross apply the remaining columns

Comment: What do you mean by use pivot and cross apply to the remaining column?

Comment: Provide some sample data and the expected result, then we can propose a solution. Attempting to bug fix a sql query with no idea what you are aiming at is like driving a car while seated backwards.

Comment: datetimestamp currentSet tGroup_id G_ID cr 4 23 24
2015-03-11 07:00:24.313 1 69 69 1 8.36 10 14.4
2015-03-12 00:31:58.257 2 69 69 2 9.12 8 14.4

Comment: In first comment it should be `Grouped columns are determined...`.  Pivoting means grouping. You are selecting p.results and spreading header. So actually you will get groupings by datetimestamp, currentset, tgroupig, gid, cr. Do you reaaly want to group by those columns?

Comment: Comments are not the vehicle for sample data as they are too small and have limited formatting, both data and result are best presented as tables.

Comment: dateTime  | currentset | tGroup_id | G_ID | cr  | 4 | 23 | 24 |

Comment: sorry i thought i have deleted that.

Comment: don't even think about using images for sample data. When this is requested it is so that we can use that data (so all we want is a simple text table). The sample is true for the expected result. I edited the question to display how it could be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am making a guess. It appears that you want to "pivot" some results so you get to see these side by side instead of across multiple rows.

While `PIVOT` has been added into many SQL implementations, it is not the only way to achieve pivoted data nor is it always the best or easiest way to do it. Here is an old fashioned "pivot" that uses a set of `case expressions` and 'GROUP BY':

```
SELECT
      PO.tGroup_id AS G_ID
    , PO.CurrentSet AS cr
    , MAX( datetimestamp ) AS datetimestamp
    , MAX( CASE WHEN gP.tTest_id = 4  THEN CONVERT(float, Po.Results) END ) AS Results4
    , MAX( CASE WHEN gP.tTest_id = 23 THEN CONVERT(float, Po.Results) END ) AS Results23
    , MAX( CASE WHEN gP.tTest_id = 24 THEN CONVERT(float, Po.Results) END ) AS Results24
FROM tPhos_Line_Operator PO
      INNER JOIN tPhos_Line_Parameter pp ON PO.tPhos_Line_Parameter_id = PP.id
      INNER JOIN tGroup_Parameter GP ON pp.tGroup_Parameter_id = gp.id
WHERE PP.tPhosline_id = 134
GROUP BY
      PO.currentSet
    , PO.tGroup_id
```

Because you haven't supplied sample data I don't know the details but hopefully you can bend this to suit your data.

---

This is an alternative approach using the `PIVOT` operator but this also relies on using `MAX() OVER()`. One complication for using the `PIVOT` operator here is that you require a maximum datetime value as well as pivoted rows which is complex using the inbuilt pivot operator. I believe that complexity can be overcome by the `MaxDateTime` column seen below:

```
SELECT
      MaxDateTime , CR, G_ID, [4], [23], [24]
FROM (
      SELECT
            PO.tGroup_id AS G_ID
          , PO.CurrentSet AS cr
          , gP.tTest_id AS Header
          , MAX( PO.datetimestamp ) OVER (PARTITION BY PO.tGroup_id, PO.CurrentSet, gP.tTest_id) AS MaxDateTime
          , CONVERT( float, Po.Results ) AS Results
      FROM tPhos_Line_Operator PO
            INNER JOIN tPhos_Line_Parameter pp ON PO.tPhos_Line_Parameter_id = PP.id
            INNER JOIN tGroup_Parameter GP ON pp.tGroup_Parameter_id = gp.id
      WHERE PP.tPhosline_id = 134
      ) AS sourve_tbl
PIVOT (MAX( Results ) FOR Header IN ([4], [23], [24])
      ) AS pvt_tbl
;
```

Comment: Thanks, i have been finding ways to supply my data, but i cant attach the image in here. The reason i used the pivot is because the tTest_id is actually a row, so i would like it to become the column. However the Test_id is also going to be dynamic. So this is a bit complicated for me.

Comment: have you tried the query at all, it WILL pivot former rows into columns, that is the whole point.

Comment: Yes I have try this.i got an error so i need to check it first.

Comment: sorry, and I also forget `END` in the case expressions... & that's why I like to get data, so I can TEST stuff.

Comment: I added an alternative to the one that worked, I think it should also work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your existing query is wrong.
I hv tried to correct it.

```
;With CTE as
(
 select Max(datetimestamp)as datetimestamp, currentSet, tGroup_id 
 from tPhos_Line_Operator 
 group by currentSet, tGroup_id
)

Select * from
 ( SELECT PO.tGroup_id AS G_ID, PO.CurrentSet AS cr,gP.tTest_id AS Header
,convert(float,Po.Results) as Results 
,T.*
from tPhos_Line_Operator PO
inner join tPhos_Line_Parameter pp
on PO.tPhos_Line_Parameter_id = PP.id
INNER JOIN tGroup_Parameter GP
on pp.tGroup_Parameter_id = gp.id
left join CTE T on T.tGroup_id = P.PO.tGroup_id
AND T.CurrentSet = PO.CurrentSet
where PP.tPhosline_id=134)tbl
PIVOT ( MAX(p.Results) For Header IN ([4],[23],[24])) AS pvt
```